# Hibernate & JPA 2.1, How to retrieve the name of a subgraph from entity graph

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa-2.1

**I try to get the name of a subgraph (defined in a annotation of entity class), but the hibernate implementation SubgraphImpl has no getter for name.**

Is there a other possibility to get the name of a subgraph programmatically?

There is a another class called NamedSubgraph, but how I get NamedSupgraph from SubgraphImpl?

What I try to do is to develop a entity graph validator, which checks by using reflection if all needed attributes nodes are defined (checking the fields of entity class with reflection). It will be also possible to exclude and include attribute nodes for partial entity graphs.

But i need the subgraph name to identify the correct subgraphs in the entity graph which should be validated.

EXAMPLE:

A working example is also available on my [github](https://github.com/jasjisdo/HibernateEntityGraphExample/tree/SimpleExample) account

four entity classes: Person, Address CreditCard and DebitCard

Person.java:

```
@Entity
@NamedEntityGraphs({
        @NamedEntityGraph(
                name = Person.EG_PROFILE_FULL,
                attributeNodes = {
                        @NamedAttributeNode(value = "wallet",
                                subgraph = Wallet.EG_PROFILE_FULL)
                }
        ),
        @NamedEntityGraph(
                name = Person.EG_PROFILE_PARTIAL,
                attributeNodes = {
                        @NamedAttributeNode(value = "wallet",
                                subgraph = Wallet.EG_PROFILE_PARTIAL)
                }
        )
})
public class Person {

    @Transient
    public transient static final String EG_PROFILE_FULL = "PersonFull";

    @Transient
    public transient static final String EG_PROFILE_PARTIAL = "PersonCreditCards";

    @Id
    long id;

    @JoinColumn(name = "wallet_id")
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    Wallet wallet;

}
```

Wallet.java:

```
@Entity
@NamedEntityGraphs({
        @NamedEntityGraph(
                name = Wallet.EG_PROFILE_FULL,
                attributeNodes = {
                        @NamedAttributeNode(value = "creditcards",
                                subgraph = CreditCard.EG_PROFILE_FULL),
                        @NamedAttributeNode(value = "debitCards",
                                subgraph = DebitCard.EG_PROFILE_FULL)
                }
        ),
        @NamedEntityGraph(
                name = Wallet.EG_PROFILE_PARTIAL,
                attributeNodes = {
                        @NamedAttributeNode(value = "creditcards",
                                subgraph = CreditCard.EG_PROFILE_FULL)
                }
        )
})
public class Wallet {

    @Transient
    public transient static final String EG_PROFILE_FULL = "WalletFull";

    @Transient
    public transient static final String EG_PROFILE_PARTIAL = "WalletCredit";

    @Id
    long id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @OrderColumn(name = "idx")
    @JoinColumn(name = "wallet_id")
    List<CreditCard> creditcards;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @OrderColumn(name = "idx")
    @JoinColumn(name = "wallet_id")
    List<DebitCard> debitCards;
}
```

CreditCard.java:

```
@Entity
@NamedEntityGraph(
        name = CreditCard.EG_PROFILE_FULL,
        attributeNodes = {
                @NamedAttributeNode(value = "number"),
                @NamedAttributeNode(value = "name")
        }
)
public class CreditCard {

    @Transient
    public transient static final String EG_PROFILE_FULL = "CreditCardFull";

    @Id
    long id;

    @Column(name="creditcard_number")
    int number;

    @Column(name="creditcard_name")
    String name;

}
```

DebitCard.java:

```
@Entity
@NamedEntityGraph(
        name = DebitCard.EG_PROFILE_FULL,
        attributeNodes = {
                @NamedAttributeNode(value = "key")
        }
)
public class DebitCard {

    @Transient
    public transient static final String EG_PROFILE_FULL = "DebitCardFull";

    @Id
    long id;

    @Column(name="debitcard_key")
    long key;

}
```

I wrote a class to print the entity graphs EntityGraphExampleMain.java:

```
public class EntityGraphExampleMain {

    protected static final String CONTEXT_LOCATION = "/inmemory-database-test-annotation-context.xml";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // get entity graph by name.
        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(CONTEXT_LOCATION);
        EntityManager em = ((EntityManagerFactory) context.getBean("entityManagerFactory")).createEntityManager();
        EntityGraphImpl<?> entityGraph = (EntityGraphImpl<?>) em.getEntityGraph(Person.EG_PROFILE_FULL);

        // print entity graph name
        System.out.println("EntityGraph = '" + entityGraph.getName() + "'");

        // print entity graph attribute node list size
        System.out.println("EntityGraph.attributeNodes.size = '" + entityGraph.getAttributeNodes().size() + "'");

        // get wallet attribute node.
        AttributeNode<?> attributeNode = entityGraph.getAttributeNodes().get(0);

        // convert and receive needed objects
        AttributeNodeImpl hbAttributeNode = (AttributeNodeImpl) attributeNode;
        Attribute jpaAttribute = hbAttributeNode.getAttribute();

        // print attribute node name
        System.out.println("AttributeNode = '" + attributeNode.getAttributeName() + "'");

        // get subgraph of wallet
        Map<Class, Subgraph> subgraphs = hbAttributeNode.getSubgraphs();

        // subgraph map should have only one entry
        System.out.println("Subgraphs.size = '" + subgraphs.entrySet().size() + "'");

        // subgraph map should contain Wallet class key.
        System.out.println("Subgraphs.keys = '" + subgraphs.keySet() + "'");

        Subgraph subgraph = subgraphs.get(subgraphs.keySet().iterator().next());
        SubgraphImpl hbSubgraph = (SubgraphImpl) subgraph;

        // print subgraph type
        System.out.println("Subgraph.type = '" + subgraph.getClassType().getName() + "'");

        // try to get subgraph attribute nodes

        // subgraph attribute node list should contian one or two elements...but it is zero!
        System.out.println("(Sub)AttributeNode.size = '" + subgraph.getAttributeNodes().size() + "'");

        /*
+        ###############################################################################################
+        #                                                                                             #
+        # need a way to identify the name of a subgraph, to get it by entity graph using entity       #
+        # manager.                                                                                    #
+        #                                                                                             #
+        # needed something like this:                                                                 #
+        #                                                                                             #
+        # String subgraphName = subgraph.getName()                                                    #
+        #                                                                                             #
+        # EntityGraphImpl<?> entityGraph = (EntityGraphImpl<?>) em.getEntityGraph(subgraphName);      #
+        #                                                                                             #
+        ###############################################################################################
+        */

    }
}
```

Console output:

```
EntityGraph = 'PersonFull'
EntityGraph.attributeNodes.size = '1'
AttributeNode = 'wallet'
Subgraphs.size = '1'
Subgraphs.keys = '[class de.hbmexample1.entity.Wallet]'
Subgraph.type = 'de.hbmexample1.entity.Wallet'
(Sub)AttributeNode.size = '0'
```

Size of attribute nodes in subgraph is 0, that is not what I expected. I need the name of the subgraph for a workaround mentioned in my code.

```
        /*
+        ###############################################################################################
+        #                                                                                             #
+        # need a way to identify the name of a subgraph, to get it by entity graph using entity       #
+        # manager.                                                                                    #
+        #                                                                                             #
+        # needed something like this:                                                                 #
+        #                                                                                             #
+        # String subgraphName = subgraph.getName()                                                    #
+        #                                                                                             #
+        # EntityGraphImpl<?> entityGraph = (EntityGraphImpl<?>) em.getEntityGraph(subgraphName);      #
+        #                                                                                             #
+        ###############################################################################################
+        */
```

Comment: I also encounterd same issue, I'm suspecious that this is hibernate bug. Hibernate vendor says that this issue has been fixed, but I still can not use subgraph function with it. I haven't tried to do it, but if we use another implementation such as eclipse link, this probram will might be able to solve.